# Dynamic Variable Name for backup table

Tags: sql, sql-server, backup

I am trying to write a stored procedure to backup a table, but I keep getting:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 9
>   The data types varchar and datetime2 are incompatible in the add operator.
>
> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   The data types varchar and datetime2 are incompatible in the add operator.

How can I fix this?

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

DECLARE @CreateDynamicSQL nvarchar(1000);
DECLARE @CopyDynamicSQL nvarchar(1000);

SET @CreateDynamicSQL='CREATE TABLE [dbo].[paul_AccountContact_Backup_'+@SYSDATETIME+'](
    [AccountID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ContactID] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO'

SET @CopyDynamicSQL='select * into [dbo].[paul_AccountContact_Backup_'+@SYSDATETIME+'] from paul_AccountContacts'

EXEC(@CreateDynamicSQL);
EXEC(@CopyDynamicSQL);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert your date variable to a string so you can concatenate it:

```
SET @CreateDynamicSQL='CREATE TABLE [dbo].[paul_AccountContact_Backup_' 
+ convert(varchar(20), @SYSDATETIME, <Format>) + '](
```

Documentation for the format parameter:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I would up declaring a time varaible as: `DECLARE @TIMENOW varchar(20)=convert(varchar(20), SYSDATETIME())`